# For each value in 1 dictionary take keys and for those keys in 2 dictionary print difference in values for all specific pairs of keys

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, dictionary

It's my first time here so sorry if I'm not conforming to some unspoken rule of the community
So i have a dictionary mydict

```
{'ENST00000309502': ['ADORA1'],
 'ENST00000337894': ['ADORA1'],
 'ENST00000618295': ['ADORA1'],
 'ENST00000380573': ['ADRA1A'],
 'ENST00000519229': ['ADRA1A'],
 'ENST00000337474': ['AVPR2'],
 'ENST00000358927': ['AVPR2'],
 'ENST00000370049': ['AVPR2'],
 'ENST00000216629': ['BDKRB1'],
 'ENST00000611804': ['BDKRB1']...}
```

And for each specific value, I need to take the keys which are keys in my second dictionary mydict2

```
{'ENST00000216629':['3.61','3.45','3.65'...]
'ENST00000255380':['3.1','3.05','3.15'...]
'ENST00000304421':['3.61','3.15','3.65'...]...}
```

And i need to find difference in values of mydict2 for each of the key for the same value in mydict
and print result like this

`mydict[value]  mydict2[key1]   mydict2[key2]  difference(list of values)`

`ADORA1  ENST00000309502  ENST00000337894  [3.61,3.25,3.14]`

I only need one combination of difference so only 1-2 not 2-1
for some values in mydict there are more than two keys.
Sorry for the long post I'm new in programming and I know I need for if loop, but im not sure how to write it.
Thanks in advance for whoever helps.

Comment: What is `key1` and `key2`?

Comment: And what's `difference`?

Comment: First of all show us what you tried.

Comment: key1 and key2 are pairs of ENST for each of value in mydict for example for ADORA1 we have 3 ENST and i need to compare their values in mydict2 so to find which element is in one and not in other for all combinations of three

Answer (score 0):

In order to loop through all possible values in `mydict`, we need a set of values in `mydict`.
*Assuming that each value (e.g. ['ADORA1']) is a list with one element*, we can flatten the list and create the set of values using

```
set_of_values = {value[0] for value in mydict.values()}
```

Then, we need the list of mydict keys corresponding to each value.
We can use list comprehension and create a new dictionary mapping each mydict value to the list of mydict keys.

```
reversed_dict = {v:[key for (key, value) in mydict.items() if value[0] == v] for v in set_of_values}
```

The rest is straightforward. For each key in reversed_dict, we can print the corresponding mydict keys and mydict2 values.

```
for (key, values) in reversed_dict.items():
    print(f'{key} {values[0]} {values[1]} {mydict2[values[0]]} {mydict2[values[1]]}')
```

This will print

```
ADORA1 ENST00000309502 ENST00000337894 [3.61,3.25,3.14, ...] ['3.1','3.05','3.15'...]
```

for example.

It is unclear what *a difference of a list* is. If you need set difference, you can use python set using, for example,

```
set1 = set(mydict2[values[0]])
set2 = set(mydict2[values[1]])
print(set1 - set2)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot thats almost  what i was looking for and yeah difference is to print elements of one ENST that are not in the other, just one question some of the values have multiple ENSts 3 or 4 so how do  I print for those all combinations of pairs of ENSTs

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are looking for something like this:

```
# Loop over the "values" in mydict1 (i.e. the string in the value)
for value in {value[0] for value in mydict1.values()}:
    
    # Find the keys in mydict1 that correspond to the selected value
    keys = tuple(key for key in mydict1 if mydict1[key] == [value])

    # Loop over pairs of distinct keys
    num_of_keys = len(keys)
    for key1, key2 in {(keys[i], keys[j])
                       for i in range(num_of_keys)
                       for j in range(i+1, num_of_keys)}:

        # Check if both keys are keys in mydict2
        if (key1 in mydict2) and (key2 in mydict2):
            
            # Calculate the difference: The elements of the values (lists) 
            # of mydict2 are strings, not numbers: What do you mean by 
            # 'difference'?
            difference = [(float(mydict2[key1]) - float(mydict2[key2][i]))
                          for i in range(len(mydict2[key1]))]

            print(value, key1, key2, difference)
```

Some things are a bit odd:

- Why are the values of mydict1 lists that contain only one string if you're actually interested in the string (it's not a problem, just a bit odd)?
- What is the "difference"? The elements in the values of mydict2 (lists) are strings, not numbers?

**EDIT**: Okay, for that kind of "difference" I'd try:

```
    ....
        
        # Check if both keys are keys in mydict2
        if (key1 in mydict2) and (key2 in mydict2):
            
            # Select all values from mydict2[key1] that are not in
            # mydict2[key2]
            difference = set(mydict2[key1]).difference(set(mydict2[key2]))
            
            print(value, key1, key2, difference)
```

Or use a list comprehension:

```
    ....
        
        # Check if both keys are keys in mydict2
        if (key1 in mydict2) and (key2 in mydict2):
            
            # Select all values from mydict2[key1] that are not in
            # mydict2[key2]
            difference = [value
                          for value in mydict2[key1] 
                          if value not in mydict2[key2]]
            
            print(value, key1, key2, difference)
```

Comment: So the difference is just which elements are in first ENST compare to the second ENST and print those elements